# Android RecyclerView layout bug

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview when it displayed for the first time the child's layout are not displayed properly:
[image]

but when i scroll to bottom and come back to the top it's good : 
[image]

I have the same problem when i change the layout for a larger.

This is my Adapter class (don't take in consideration the diffents type,this is not the source of the bug because the bug exist too when i have one ViewHolder type)

```
 private class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private static final int TYPE_ALERTS = 0 ;
    private static final int TYPE_MOST_VIEWED = 1 ;



    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder (final ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {


        if (viewType == TYPE_ALERTS){

            View itemLayoutView =  LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.layout_item_alerts_home_home, null);

            ViewHolderAlerts viewHolderAlerts = new ViewHolderAlerts(itemLayoutView);

            itemLayoutView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick (View v) {


                        Intent intent = new Intent(activity, Activity_UpdateAlert.class);
                        intent.putExtra("alert", (AlertObj)listAllProducts.get(recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(v)));

                        startActivity(intent);

                }
            });

            return viewHolderAlerts;

        }else {

            View itemLayoutView =  LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.layout_item_product_grid__list_products_by_category, null);

            ViewHolder_Product_CatSearch viewHolder_product_catSearch = new ViewHolder_Product_CatSearch(itemLayoutView);

            itemLayoutView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick (View v) {


                    Intent intent = new Intent(activity, Activity_ProductDetails.class);
                    intent.putExtra("product", (Product)listAllProducts.get(recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(v)));

                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            });

            return  viewHolder_product_catSearch ;

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder (RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        if (getItemViewType(position) == TYPE_ALERTS){

            ((ViewHolderAlerts)holder).textViewTitle.setText(((AlertObj)listAllProducts.get(position)).product.name);
            ((ViewHolderAlerts)holder).textViewPrice.setText(new DecimalFormat("###0.00")
                    .format(Double.valueOf(((AlertObj)listAllProducts.get(position)).product.price)) +
                    ((AlertObj)listAllProducts.get(position)).product.currency);

            Glide.with(activity.getApplicationContext())
                    .load(((AlertObj)listAllProducts.get(position)).product.imgUrl)
                            .error(R.drawable.picture_not_available)
                            .into(((ViewHolderAlerts) holder).imgView);

        }else {

            ((ViewHolder_Product_CatSearch)holder).textViewName.setText(((ProductMostViews)listAllProducts.get(position)).name);
            ((ViewHolder_Product_CatSearch)holder).textViewPrice.setText(new DecimalFormat("###0.00")
                    .format(Double.valueOf(((ProductMostViews)listAllProducts.get(position)).price)) +
                    ((ProductMostViews)listAllProducts.get(position)).currency);

            Glide.with(activity.getApplicationContext())
                    .load(((ProductMostViews)listAllProducts.get(position)).imgUrl)
                    .error(R.drawable.picture_not_available)
                    .into(((ViewHolder_Product_CatSearch) holder).imageViewProduct);


        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType (int position) {

       return listAllProducts.get(position) instanceof AlertObj ? TYPE_ALERTS : TYPE_MOST_VIEWED ;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId (int position) {
        return listAllProducts.get(position) instanceof AlertObj ? TYPE_ALERTS : TYPE_MOST_VIEWED ;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount () {
        return listAllProducts.size();
    }
}
```

Thank's

Comment: You put the code for your adapter, but your adapter just supplies the Views to be layed out.  They look identical in both screenshots, nothing looks wrong with the adapter.  It's the layout and layout manager  you're having problems with,